# Gatsby graphql or condition on two different fields

Tags: gatsby

Is it possible to add an OR operator on two different fields on gatsby?

I'm trying to execute a query like this:

```
{
    allFile(filter: {
        OR: [
            {absolutePath: {
                    eq: "/Users/jesusyepes/Documents/webs/lego-gatsby/src/images/site-icon.jpg"
                }},

            {atime: {
                    eq: "/Users/jesusyepes/Documents/webs/lego-gatsby/src/images/site-icon2.jpg"
                }},
        ]

    }) {
        nodes {
            absolutePath
            id
        }
    }
}
```

Which throws the following error:
Field \"OR\" is not defined by type FileFilterInput.

Looking at their [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/), they say "Gatsby relies on Sift to enable MongoDB-like query syntax for object filtering."

On [Sift](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sift) documentation I see OR is supported:

```
[
  { name: "Craig", state: "MN" },
  { name: "Tim", state: "MN" },
  { name: "Joe", state: "CA" }
].filter(sift({ $or: [{ name: "Craig" }, { state: "MN" }] }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `OR` is not supported at the time of this answer ([here's a list of all supported operators](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#complete-list-of-possible-operators.))

One work around is to make do with a query with 2 alias:

```
query {
  fileOne: allFile(filter: { ... }) { ... }
  fileTwo: allFile(filter: { ... }) { ... }
}
```

...and then merge them manually in JS.

Comment: not a very feasible solution, but thanks ;) Will wait for the adoption of gatsby and check it back a few months from now.